# Spark order by second field to perform timeseries function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv with a timeseries:

```
timestamp, measure-name, value, type, quality

1503377580,x.x-2.A,0.5281250,Float,GOOD
1503377340,x.x-1.B,0.0000000,Float,GOOD
1503377400,x.x-1.B,0.0000000,Float,GOOD
```

The measure-name should be my partition key and I would like to calculate a moving average with pyspark, here my code (for instance) to calculate the max

```
def mysplit(line):
    ll = line.split(",")
    return (ll[1],float(ll[2]))

text_file.map(lambda line: mysplit(line)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: max(a , b)).foreach(print)
```

However, for the average I would like to respect the timestamp ordering.

**How to order by a second column?**

Comment: Can you detail what is you expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a window function on pyspark dataframes:

First you should transform your rdd to a dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
df = hc.createDataFrame(text_file.map(lambda l: l.split(','), ['timestamp', 'measure-name', 'value', 'type', 'quality'])
```

Or load it directly as a dataframe:

- local:

  ```py
  import pandas as pd
  df = hc.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, sep=",", header=0))
  ```
- from hdfs:

  ```py
  df = hc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ",").load(path_to_csv)
  ```

Then use a window function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
w = Window.orderBy('timestamp')
df.withColumn('value_rol_mean', psf.mean('value').over(w))

    +----------+------------+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+
    | timestamp|measure_name|   value| type|quality|     value_rol_mean|
    +----------+------------+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+
    |1503377340|     x.x-1.B|     0.0|Float|   GOOD|                0.0|
    |1503377400|     x.x-1.B|     0.0|Float|   GOOD|                0.0|
    |1503377580|     x.x-2.A|0.528125|Float|   GOOD|0.17604166666666665|
    +----------+------------+--------+-----+-------+-------------------+
```

in `.orderBy`you can order by as many columns as you want